# How do I access the selected items in Kendo UI's ListView?

Tags: listview, kendo-ui

I love the control and from visual perspective it provides me with exactly what I want (selecting multiple items, etc) but I don't see any documentation or tutorials explaining how to access a collection with the selected items or even determine which items are selected.

I thank you in advance for you help with such a basic question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `select` method for getting the list of nodes selected.

Given the following initialization:

```
var list = $("#list").kendoListView({
    dataSource: data,
    template  : "<li>${title}</li>",
    selectable: "multiple"
}).data("kendoListView");
```

You can use:

```
var selected = list.select();
console.log("selected", selected);
```

Check the documentation about `select` [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/listview#select)

Comment: Than you. Of course I saw `select` in the documentation and read **Selects the specified ListView item.** and stopped before I got to *If called without arguments - returns the selected items.*

Comment: where in this documentation does it specify the return type of the select function? I get that you can do .select().length to get the number of items selected, but the documentation doesn't talk about how to match the selected item with a record in the dataSource does it?

Comment: It says that the return type is a `jQuery` object.  Also you have to do something like (untested): `$.map($('#my-list-view').data('kendoListView').select(), function(item) {
            return $(item).index();
        });` to get the indices of the items.